# How do I display and Deserialize RiotAPI Data into WinForms?

Tags: c#, json, winforms

I'm trying to create a winforms app that enables the user to input a LoL Username and on pressing the button it generates the SummonerV4 API info from Riot. I'm having trouble figuring this out. [Image of form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGpIt.png)

This is what the code for the actual form is looking like currently. I get thrown exceptions because RiotAPI is Null. What would I need to add to get this running?

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using MingweiSamuel.Camille;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RiotAPI_ESavage
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.PopulateLoLDataGridView();
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public object apiResponse { get; private set; }

    private async void GetAPIData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var response = await SummonerV4.GetALL();
        apiResponse = response;//.text  = response;
        this.PopulateLoLDataGridView();
    }

    private void PopulateLoLDataGridView()
    {
        string apiUrl = "https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/";
        object input = new
        {
            Name = textBox1.Text.Trim(),
        };
        string inputJson =

        RiotAPI.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
        RiotAPI.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        string json = RiotAPI.UploadString(apiUrl + "/GetSummonerInfo", inputJson);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataGridView1;
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private WebClient RiotAPI;




    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You need to deserialize the json first. Did you attempt to do that? What issue you are facing in that?

Comment: You don't seem to ever assign a value to `RiotAPI`